# What are the real risks of enabling unsecure DNS updates on Active Directory intranet domain?

Tags: dns, active-directory, dns-domain

Based on my current research, enabling the unsecure DNS updates is a requirement for enabling DHCP Linux clients from registering their names with a FQDN.

While this works fine for Windows machines joined into the domain, the same doesn't work for Linux clients without enabling these unsecure updates.

As far as I know a machine would not be able to takeover another reserved name which would be the only real concern that I now.

Obviously it would be the DDOS but considering that we are talking about intranet here, I doubt this could be a real risk.

Do you have it enable on your domain or not?

Did you ever had to disable it due to having some problems with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use secure dynamic updates only the domain members can update their entries. This is achieved by using kerberos to authentificate the client towards the DNS-Server. This authentification funcionality does not seem to be implemented in Linux DNS-Clients and this is why you need to enable unsecure dynamic updates.

Unsecure dynamic updates allow one to update its own DNS record without authentification. This is clearly a threat because DNS is a UDP based protocol and the source address can easily be spoofed on a LAN.

On the other hand this is a very bad documented functionality and there are no tools publicly available that could be used to migrate this attack.

I did never migrate this attack but there are some risks I can think of.

- Duplicate Names in DNS Server - Will either result in DoS or prevent a correct functionality of resolving the hostname
- WPAD redirection. If you name your host `wpad` and setup a webserver that provides a proxy configuration you can pass a proxy configuration to internet explorer and chrome users. This is part of the [WPAD](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol) protocol. The worst thing is that you can force the internet explorer to expose the authentificated users password hash by asking for NTLM authentification. I know its unbelivable but this can also be achieved by NBNS and LLMNR Poisoning using the tool `Responder`.

// This really got my interest when I got time Im going to write a POC tool that uses this vulnerability.